# Two DIV elements are not stacking correctly on mobile

Tags: php, html, css

My CSS and HTML are not working. `div2` should render below `div1` but it's not working on mobile.

```css
#div1 {
    width:100%
}

#div2 {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id = "main">
    <div id = "div1">
        
    </div>
    
    <div id = "div2">
         
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide your HTML as well, and ensure us that this is all of your CSS (you aren't using anything else, like a library or Bootstrap?)

Comment: Your code should work fine. Is there other CSS that might be affecting the site on mobile?

Comment: All `div`s are width 100% by default because they are 'block' level elements `

Comment: Most likely, `#main` has `display: flex;`, in which case either `#main { display: block;}` or `#main {flex-wrap: wrap}` should fix your problem. Please create a [mcve] and provide more detail. Currently, the cause of the described behavior is impossible to determine from what you shared.

Comment: your sample code is incomplete. first, the `div`s are empty so you can't see the `div`s at all, put something in it. second, even without your css, those `div`s should be stacked vertically as the default behavior. therefore you won't get an answer by that code alone https://jsfiddle.net/7rhtyjdh/

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
   display:inline-block
}
#div1 {
  width: 100%
}

#div2 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="div1">

  </div>
  <div id="div2">

  </div>
</div>
```

making the divs diplay inline:block should solve the problem

Comment: Did you stop and ask yourself why they're not acting as blocks even though they are `<div>`s and have `width:100%`? Most probably, `#main` has `display:flex` with `flex-wrap: nowrap` (default), in which case, `#main {flex-wrap: wrap;}` should solve the problem. Please try to avoid answering questions without a [mcve], especially if the cause of the bug is impossible to determine with the provided information. For details see [answer].

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
#div1,#div2 {
   width: 100%
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```